# how can put the np.loadtxt result to array

Tags: python, numpy

I whant to put the np.loadtxt to new array but I got too many indices error

```
data = np.loadtxt('lab_iris_data.csv', dtype={'names': ('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'label'),'formats': (np.float, np.float, np.float, '|S15')}, delimiter=',', skiprows=0)

x = data[:,0:2]
y = data[:,-1]
print (data)
```

> ----> 9 x = data[:,0:2]
>        10 #y = data[:,-1]
>        11 print (data)
>   IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Hint: print `data` after loading it.

Comment: Your tutorial should have shown you how to access the fields of this 1d array - by name, not column number.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you have declared contents for your array that don't fit it.If we assume it to be one dimensional and the program is opposing to  treat it like a 2 dimensional. So, check your declarations whether they are correct or not and also test the code by printing the values after you've set them to double check they are what you intend them to be.

`IndexError: too many indices for array` occurs because if there is too many index values.

For Example : You given two values as you're expecting data to be a 2D array. It is complaining because data is not 2D . It either 1 dimensional or empty array, you might get an array returned that is either 1D or even empty

Comment: We don't have 'declairations' in python